# ¿Como sobrecargar métodos en PHP?

Tags: java, php

Yo se que la sobre carga de métodos o funciones en Java se hacer así.

```
public int opera(int n1,int n2){

  int resultado=n1+n2;
  return resultado;
}

public int opera(int n1,int n2,int n3){

  int resultado=(n1+n2)*n3;
  return resultado;
}
```

Pero en `PHP` me da error hacer algo así pero con la sintaxis de `PHP` me dice error:

> Cannot redeclare class::opera()

Si trato de hacerlo de esta manera me da error de sintaxis.

```
public function opera($n1,$n2[,$n3]) {
  if(isset($n3)){
    $resultado=(n1+n2)*n3;
  }else{
    $resultado=n1+n2;
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La sobrecarga de métodos en *PHP* es diferente a *Java*:

> La interpretación de *PHP* para sobrecarga es diferente a otros lenguajes. La sobrecarga tradicionalmente proporciona la habilidad de tener múltiples métodos con el mismo nombre pero con diferente cantidad de tipos y argumentos.

Función para encontrar la suma de `n` números:

```
function findSum(){
  $sum = 0;
  foreach( func_get_args() as $arg ){
   $sum += $arg;
  }
}
echo findSum(1,2); // salida 3
echo findSum(10,2,100); //salida 112
```

Para tu ejemplo podría ser algo así:

```
function opera(){
  $resultado = 0;
  $args = func_get_args();
  if ( count(func_get_args()) == 3)
    $resultado=($args[0]+$args[1])*$args[2];
  elseif ( count(func_get_args()) == 2 )
    $resultado = $args[0]+$args[1];

  return $resultado;
}
echo opera(1,2) . "<br>"; //salida 3
echo opera(1,2,3) . "<br>"; //salida 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Pudieras hacer algo como

```
public function opera($var1, $var2=null){
    if(is_null($var2)){
       $var2 = 500;
    }

    return $var1+$var2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar parámetros opcionales. Más o menos algo así:

```
public function opera($n1,$n2,$n3=null) {
    if($n3 != null){
        $resultado=(n1+n2)*n3;
    }else{
        $resultado=n1+n2;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```